Regarding session layer of OSI model
I was looking into OSI model and I couldn't understand how does session layer enable session between sender and recipient internally. Only after the session layer there is transport, network, data link, physical any data can be physically transported right then. How could a session be made between end devices and will the data from presentation layer be enclosed with additional header for session purpose?
Sorry if my doubt was answered somewhere, but I couldn't just find the right answer to my question
Caution: I am not a CS student please reduce more technical terms

What do you define as a 'session' though? The specification for this layer probably doesn't match the modern-networking definition of that word.

There are two stackoverflow links
ISO/OSI Network protocol
Actually sending data trought Internet is pretty hard. To do this, programmers created the network layers.
Historically two network stack were born: TCP/IP (the de facto standard) and ISO/OSI (the de iure standard).
You can think network layers like "subproblems". Actually each layer resolve a specific subproblem.
The first layer is the physical layer. We could say "it simply sends raws of bits trough a physical cable".
Once I know I can "send bits" I can now send data trought my cable. So a particular sequence of bits is data I wanna send to receiver. But how can receiver know if bits he receives are "physical bits" or "data link bits"?.
Every layer add an header portion to data sent. Actually, the header is a sequence of bit. When data is sent from data link layer, it goes "down" the stack and reach physical layer. Physical layer adds some bits to data, so when packet is received by the receiver, he removes "additional bits" that sender layers added. Removing additional bits multiple times, receiver can actually know what "sender sent me" and what layer sender wanna communicate with me.
Example (with TCP/IP stack)
I wanna visit a site. When I open my web browser and type the name of the site, the web browser contact a server and asks "Hey, Could I actually see this website" trought HTTP , which is a protocol in a layer of the protocol stack. BUT to send an HTTP request I must be sure I can contact this server first, and I can do this thanks to a TCP channel, BUT I must be sure connection is secure, BUT to send bits I must have the physical layer ...
So I send the HTTP, it goes down the stack and each layer "adds" an header (REMINDER: a sequence of bits) to it. When receiver gets the package, he takes it and says "oh ok, I see the packet he sent me actually has a certain sequence of bits which I know is the header for the physical layer", so receiver remove this header and send the rest to data link layer, etc.
So the answer to your question

how does session layer enable session between sender and recipient internally

Is that you know underlying layers "resolve" the problems to send bits, send them to someone with a specific identifier (IP for TCP/IP stack) ... and you only have to add "something more" to create a session between you and someone else.
HOW you do it depends on protocol you are using.
NOTE: layer and protocol are two different concepts. A layer is the "logical subproblem" you wanna resolve, the protocol is the actual implementation you use. Just to say, in TCP/IP stack there is the "transport layer" which actually resolve the subproblem of create a session and manage it. You can do this using the TCP protocol or the UDP protocol, which "resolve the subproblem" but in different ways, with pros and cons...
In session layer you want to manage a session between end users, so you want that an host A send requests to host B (and host B can reply) over an insecure channel.
I suggest you to read link I sent you to have a better comprehension of what a network stack is and how ISO/OSI model works
Greetings

Thanks i read those links you marked, this is what i understood,
NetBIOS usually operates over TCP/IP networks, meaning it uses TCP or UDP at the transport layer. TCP/UDP in turn, relies on IP at the network layer, and the entire stack relies on the physical layer to transmit the data. so session layer protocols insert some data for session mgmt, termination too and sends the overall data transmitted from sender to receiver and receiver unpacks to know the session request and responds like that ? or do i miss something

Correct. Just a note: remember layer and protocol are two different concepts. NetBIOS usually operates over TCP/IP networks, meaning it uses TCP or UDP at the transport layer TCP and UDP are the "most famous" protocol of transport layer, but they are not the transport layer. Actually a protocol of application layer could use TCP, UDP, DCCP, SCTP... see link for more details. Same for IP, maybe a protocol doesn't need "IP features" and uses something smaller (like ICMP). so session layer protocols insert some bits  (his header)
